# Maintaining double quotes during concatenation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a webapp to have copy onclick text however the way javascript is concatenating my strings which form the li html elements it is replacing "" in my element selector with '' which is breaking my functionality. I have tried replacing with string escapes but to no avail.

My commented-out html is an example of a working function and what I intend to do.

```js
var responseList = [
  'Text',
  'also text',
  'Some text!',
  'Some more text..'
];
var concatHTML = '';
var concatHTML2 = [];
function print(message, i) {
  concatHTML += '\r<li>' + '<p id=\"p' + i + '\" onclick=\'copyToClipboard(\"#p' + i +"\')\'>" + message + "</p>\r";
  console.log(concatHTML);
  document.getElementById("respUL").innerHTML = concatHTML;
}

for (var i = 0; i < responseList.length; i++) {
  print(responseList[i], i);
}

function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<h1>Click & Paste</h1>
  <h2>Making a list of things to click on then paste</h2>

<ul id="respUL">
  
</ul>
<!-- <p id="p1" onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')">Text
</p>
<p id="p2" onclick="copyToClipboard('#p2')">Hi, I'm the 2nd TEXT</p><br/> -->
</div>
```

Comment: You have a typo: `i +"\')\'>" + message` should be `i +"\")\'>" + message` Also, you don't have to escape single quotes inside double quotes.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you refactoring this a bit so that you don't have to insert string concated html into the DOM. Errors like this are not unusual when doing this. You might think about having a hidden template elem in the DOM then cloning it, altering it, and appending it back all in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fairly easy if you stop using `innerHTML` and create the required DOM nodes:

```
function print(message, i) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.id = i;
    p.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        copyToClipboard("#p"+i);
    }, false);
    p.textContent = message;
    li.appendChild(p);
    document.getElementById("respUL").appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Rob! Just learning about the innerHTML and haven't touched DOM manipulation much. Deeply appreciated the time you took for this!

Comment: No problem @ThomasC, glad to help out. Good luck with your learning!